# Get record by rownum and column 'status'

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I am using spring boot @transactional to process records of a table one by one.
My oracle Db has column status which has value as 'A'.
I change the status to 'Y' for a successful transaction, otherwise do nothing.
I am using the following query to get the record:

```
SELECT * from 
  (SELECT e.*,ROWNUM  rn 
   from TABLE_A e 
   where status!='Y' 
   order by TABLE_A_ID) 
WHERE rn =:rownum;
```

The value of rownum increases by one for every transaction.

I am facing the issue that this query skips a record after every successful transaction.
i.e it fetches as record1 then record 3 then record 5 and so on.

Comment: If you change the status to Y then the next time you run your query the changed datarow will of course no longer be part of the resultset and what was previously row 2 will now be row 1.

Comment: correct. i need help in modifying the query so that I get all records to process.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve from your query. If you post expected output and some sample data, we might try to provide the query you need.

Comment: Don't you just want the first unprocessed row each time? Why are you incrementing `:rownum` at all?

Comment: because in that case, if my transaction fails for one record, I will get the same record again and again for processing in the subsequent transactions.

Comment: Instead of getting single data rows by slecting the ROWNUM i think it would probably be easier if you selected all rows in the query and processed them with a scrollable resultset or something similar.